# materialize css double modal

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

When I show one modal, and an action inside this modal displays another modal, all the screen gets opacity, and that's annoying of course.

I see that materialize creates an element, at the end of the DOM:

```
<div class="lean-overlay" id="materialize-lean-overlay-1" style="z-index: 1002; display: block;opacity: 0.5;"></div>
<div class="lean-overlay" id="materialize-lean-overlay-2" style="z-index: 1004; display: block;opacity: 0.5;"></div>
```

I should set the opacity of the last element to 0.

But I think this solution won't work in all cases (sometimes is `id="materialize-lean-overlay-XXX"`). I can loop all `class="lean-overlay"` elements, and set the opacity of the last element to 0, but not sure if it's the best solution.

What do you think? Thanks!!

Comment: I think you need to share some code.

Comment: I resolved the problem some days ago, I share the code if it could help someone. The function to open the second modal (delete confirmation modal) is:

   _displayModalDelete: function() {
        $('#modalDelete').openModal();
        var length = $(".lean-overlay").length-1;
        $(".lean-overlay")[1].style.opacity="0";
        $(".lean-overlay")[1].style.zIndex="0";
    }

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem some days ago, I share the code if it could help someone. The function to open the second modal (delete confirmation modal) is:

```
 _displayModalDelete: function() {
      $('#modalDelete').openModal();
      var length = $(".lean-overlay").length-1;
      $(".lean-overlay")[1].style.opacity="0";
      $(".lean-overlay")[1].style.zIndex="0";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the oppacity of the father modal and run

Answer (score 0):

Having the second modal element at the same level as the first modal, and not inside it, should help you avoid this problem without the hassle of dealing with css properties.